# how to get access control lists for an object in documentum using dql query

Tags: java, dql, documentum, dfc, documentum-dfc

I need the access control lists of an object in documentum by running the dql query 
and also does an object in documentum have only 1 access control list or multiple access control lists 
please help me

I am new to documentum

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your DQL?

Comment: I dont know how to get acl by dql query,I dont have any dql query,please help me

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?